# Exchange 2010 Prepare Domain in server 2003 32bit environment

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2010

We plan to add Exchange 2010 to our 2003 environment.

On the primary DC, we try to prepare the domain (windows server 2003  Sp2 32 bit). How can we apply the schema and forest preparations even if the version of setup.exe that comes with the Exchange Server 2010 installation media will run only on computers with a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: Is the computer you are installing on a 32-bit or just Server 2003?

Comment: To run Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 you need:


**Computer** —An x64 architecture-based computer with Intel processor that supports Intel Extended Memory 64 Technology (Intel EM64T) or AMD processor that supports the AMD64 platform; Intel Itanium family IA64 processors are not supported.


**Operating system** —Microsoft Windows Server 2008 x64 Standard and Enterprise Edition with Service Pack 2 or Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and Enterprise Edition. **Source** - http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/exchange/system-requirements.aspx

Comment: ServerFaulter: you might want to post that as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to actually run the preparation steps on a domain controller; you can run them on any domain-joined computer, including the one(s) where you are going to install Exchange. Just make sure to run them using an appropriately privileged user account (Enteprise Admin, Schema Admin, Domain Admin).

Comment: +1 - Install and setup the machines that will eventually run Exchange and run the DC prep tools from them BEFORE installing Exchange.